# Wondering if I could use APPLY here instead of using FOR LOOP for optimization in this case?

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm setting up an equation of getting the netvalues of the stock combinations.

The original equation:

net values of stock * weight.stock/ number of stock types + bond * weight.bond/ number of bond types + cash * weight.cash/ number of cash types

for a sequence of dates.

The method of matching: For instance, any rows in BackTest.table with date before 2008-7-15 will match the first row in Weight.table (which covers the dates from 2008-5-01 to 2008-7-15.)

Here is a chunk of the BackTest.table for easier imagination. Headers of this table are: Date, stock type1, stock type2, ..., bond type 1, bond type2, ..., cash type 4. (Which is just an example of type numbers) It actually matches the type numbers in Weight.table.

```
         Date s1         s2           s3 s4 s5 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 c1 c2 c3 c4
2  2008-07-01  0 -3.0158124 -0.055652040  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  2008-07-02  0  0.3838345 -0.119046476  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  2008-07-03  0  2.7602604  0.009611965  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  2008-07-04  0 -0.5370067 -0.009611041  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  2008-07-05  0  0.0000000  0.000000000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  2008-07-06  0  0.0000000  0.000000000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  2008-07-07  0  5.1583803  0.032680681  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9  2008-07-08  0  0.8500539  0.048044124  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10 2008-07-09  0  3.6352579  0.048981473  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11 2008-07-10  0 -1.5689846  0.052797297  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12 2008-07-11  0 -0.6688334  0.045093882  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13 2008-07-12  0  0.0000000  0.000000000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14 2008-07-13  0  0.0000000  0.000000000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15 2008-07-14  0  1.0436299  0.033565414  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16 2008-07-15  0 -3.8589001  0.004793450  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17 2008-07-16  0 -4.0513392  0.034511187  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
18 2008-07-17  0 -1.0070062  0.009583134  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
19 2008-07-18  0  3.5303394  0.014373323  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
20 2008-07-19  0  0.0000000  0.000000000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
21 2008-07-20  0  0.0000000  0.000000000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Here's another chunk of the Weight.table for easier imagination.

```
Date          Stock  Numbers1 Bond  Number2 Cash     Number3
1 2008-04-30 0.0642        5 0.7858       2 0.1500       2
2 2008-07-15 0.0801        5 0.7699       2 0.1500       2
3 2008-07-31 0.0727        6 0.7773       2 0.1500       1
4 2008-10-31 0.1373        4 0.7127       2 0.1500       1
5 2008-11-30 0.1457        3 0.7144       2 0.1399       2
6 2009-01-31 0.1791        5 0.7242       2 0.0967       1
```

Here are the dputs of header of Weight.table and BackTest.table

```
dput(head(Weight.table))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(13999, 14075, 14091, 14183, 
14213, 14275), class = "Date"), Stock = c(0.0642, 0.0801, 0.0727, 
0.1373, 0.1457, 0.1791), Numbers1 = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L), 
    Bond = c(0.7858, 0.7699, 0.7773, 0.7127, 0.7144, 0.7242), 
    Number2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 现金 = c(0.15, 0.15, 
    0.15, 0.15, 0.1399, 0.0967), Number3 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(head(BackTest.table))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14061, 14062, 14063, 14064, 
14065, 14066), class = "Date"), s1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s2 = c(-3.01581241943634, 
0.383834486785705, 2.76026041158503, -0.537006711952127, 0, 0
), s3 = c(-0.0556520404148886, -0.119046476128297, 0.00961196497399089, 
-0.00961104116408056, 0, 0), s4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), s5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), b3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), c1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

However, it takes a bit long to get what I want. So I was trying to use sapply, but the results are different. It seems like the sapply didnt go through the IFELSE process?

To get the values, I have set a constant k, whenever the dates in Backtest.table matches the dates in Weight.table, k = k+1, so it moves to the next row and uses the new weights to calculate the netvalues.

The original code that worked:

```
k <- 1

for (t in 1:nrow(BackTest.table)) {
if (BackTest.table[t, 1] %in% Weight.table[, 1] == FALSE) {
    NetReturnPt.table[t, 2] <- sum(BackTest.table[t, 2: ncol(BackTest.table)]* 
    c(rep(Weight.table[k, 2]/ Weight.table[k, 3], Weight.table[k, 3]),
      rep(Weight.table[k, 4]/ Weight.table[k, 5], Weight.table[k, 5]),
      rep(Weight.table[k, 6]/ Weight.table[k, 7], Weight.table[k, 7])
      ), na.rm = TRUE)
  } 
  else {NetReturnPt.table[t, 2] <- sum(BackTest.table[t, 2: ncol(BackTest.table)]* 
        c(rep(Weight.table[k, 2]/ Weight.table[k, 3], Weight.table[k, 3]),
          rep(Weight.table[k, 4]/ Weight.table[k, 5], Weight.table[k, 5]),
          rep(Weight.table[k, 6]/ Weight.table[k, 7], Weight.table[k, 7])
          ), na.rm = TRUE)
k <- k + 1
  }
}

dput(head(NetReturnPt.table[, 2]))
[1] -0.026597604  0.016239878  0.048405161  0.005821428  0.012840000  0.012840000
dput(NetReturnPt.table[20:25, 2])
[1]  0.016020000  0.073282388  0.014539880  0.003858773  0.065490672 -0.003378064
```

The APPLY function that doesn't give the right values after the first few data:

```
k <- 1

TestApply <- function(t) {
if (BackTest.table[t, 1] %in% Weight.table[, 1] == FALSE) {
    NetReturnPt.table[t, 2] <- sum(BackTest.table[t, 2: ncol(BackTest.table)] * 
    c(rep(Weight.table[k, 2]/ Weight.table[k, 3], Weight.table[k, 3]),
      rep(Weight.table[k, 4]/ Weight.table[k, 5], Weight.table[k, 5]),
      rep(Weight.table[k, 6]/ Weight.table[k, 7], Weight.table[k, 7])
      ), na.rm = TRUE)
  } 
  else { NetReturnPt.table[t, 2] <- sum(BackTest.table[t, 2:ncol(BackTest.table)] * 
       c(rep(Weight.table[k, 2]/ Weight.table[k, 3], Weight.table[k, 3]),
         rep(Weight.table[k, 4]/ Weight.table[k, 5], Weight.table[k, 5]),
         rep(Weight.table[k, 6]/ Weight.table[k, 7], Weight.table[k, 7])
         ), na.rm = TRUE)
k <- k + 1
  }
}

test.result <- sapply(1: nrow(BackTest.table), function(t) TestApply(t))
dput(head(test.result))
[1] -0.026597604  0.016239878  0.048405161  0.005821428  0.012840000  0.012840000
dput(test.result[20:25])
[1]  0.012840000  0.058735697  0.011653687  0.003092799  0.052490651 -0.002707512
```

You can see that the first few values are same as the one using FORLOOP. Therefore, I am wondering if it didnt go through the IFELSE process.

Thank you for your precious time, and I would like to thank Steven Lee for telling me the better way to show my codes.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the two tables and what the headers of `Backtest.table` are, and where the data rows start -- I think the 2nd row here? Could you please include the output of `dput(head(Backtest.table))` and `dput(head(Weight.table))` in the body of your question?

Comment: @JonSpring The headers of Backtest.table are date, stock type 1, stock type 2, stock type3, ... , bond type 1, bond type2, ... , cash type 1. The values are the gain/loss in percentage of each fund type on that specific date. The data rows actually start from the first row, since i omitted the previous first row, now the first row has the row number 2. I have included dput(head(Weight.table)) in the body and now I just added dput(head(Backtest.table)). Thank you for your time Jon!

Comment: @jogo Thanks for reminding, I just added the output of dput().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggested approach. As January suggested, this should be straightforward if you restructure your data.

Here, I reshape `Weight.table` so each row shows the weight and number for each class and date. Note, I altered the first two dates in your example data so that they'd match with the other table.

```
library(tidyverse)
Weight.table.tidy <- Weight.table %>%
  # Renaming here so the first character represents the class, and the second
  #  character represents (w)eight or (n)number.
  rename(s_w = "Stock", s_n = "Numbers1",
         b_w = "Bond",  b_n = "Number2",
         c_w = "现金",  c_n = "Number3") %>%
  gather(col, val, -Date) %>% 
  separate("col", c("class", "stat")) %>%
  spread(stat, val)

head(Weight.table.tidy)
#         Date class n      w
#1  2008-07-01     b 2 0.7858
#2  2008-07-01     c 2 0.1500
#3  2008-07-01     s 5 0.0642
#4  2008-07-04     b 2 0.7699
#5  2008-07-04     c 2 0.1500
#6  2008-07-04     s 5 0.0801
```

Now I do something similar for `BackTest.table`, reshaping into long form so that each row holds one `Date`, `class`, and `num`, with the corresponding value from the original table. Then we can join this to `Weight.table.tidy` and fill down to all the NA dates based on prior dates within each class+num group. Now we have a long list of values, along with the variables we'll be using to weight each one.

```
BackTest.table.tidy <- BackTest.table %>%
  gather(type, val, -Date) %>%
  separate("type", c("class", "num"), sep = 1) %>% 
  left_join(Weight.table.tidy) %>%
  group_by(class, num) %>%
  fill(n, w) %>% ungroup()

head(BackTest.table.tidy)
## A tibble: 6 x 6
#  Date       class num     val     n     w
#  <date>     <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2008-07-01 b     1         0     2 0.786
#2 2008-07-02 b     1         0     2 0.786
#3 2008-07-03 b     1         0     2 0.786
#4 2008-07-04 b     1         0     2 0.770
#5 2008-07-05 b     1         0     2 0.770
#6 2008-07-06 b     1         0     2 0.770
```

One reshaped, we can use one line to weight the value, and another to sum for each Date. As a vectorized solution, I expect it will be much faster than the original solution.

```
BackTest.table.tidy %>% 
  mutate(val_wtd = val * w / n) %>%
  count(Date, wt = val_wtd)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggested approach, and it looks much more efficient. However, when I tried to run BackTest.table.tidy, the column n and w are filled with NAs, it did not fill the numbers the way in your table. Im am wondering why.

Comment: There might be a better way to join the two tables, maybe by filling in the missing dates to `Weight.table` with `padr::pad` or `dplyr::complete`, or by using `data.table` or `fuzzyjoin` to do a non-equi data join. I think my answer here relies on the first BackTest Date existing within the Weight.table Dates, which sounds like an unreliable assumption. If you look farther down, are the `n` and `w` columns filled in once the Weight.table Dates begin?

Answer (score 1):

OMG, this is confusing. It appears that if you get your data structures right, you won't have to loop at all, but simply divide or multiply the columns of a suitable data frame.

The reason why your code does not work is that k is now an internal variable to the function argument of `sapply`. `sapply` calls `TestApply` repeatedly for each of the rows of your BackTest.table, but each time `TestApply` is called, k remains 1, since `k <- k + 1` has no effect outside of `TestApply`.

One way of dealing with that would be to use `k <<- k + 1`, which makes the assignment in the parent environments (specifically, the first parent environment that has a `k` variable defined). While I suppose this will work, this is neither an elegant nor a safe solution. In general, functions should only influence their environment by returning a value (changing `k` is called a "side effect" and is generally not encouraged).

Far much better would be to think how to clean up, match and extract the data frames into one which you could then use for calculations in a simple and straightforward way. Here I cannot help you: you would need to tell us way more about your tables (perhaps in another question).

Another approach would be to start with the following code:

```
sum(BackTest.table[t, 2: ncol(BackTest.table)] * 
   c(rep(Weight.table[k, 2]/ Weight.table[k, 3], Weight.table[k, 3]),
     rep(Weight.table[k, 4]/ Weight.table[k, 5], Weight.table[k, 5]),
     rep(Weight.table[k, 6]/ Weight.table[k, 7], Weight.table[k, 7])
```

This code is evil. It is confusing, you don't know what it does (it appears to make a weird attempt at getting a weighted mean, but there are much faster ways of doing that, for example `weighted.mean`), and it depends on the number of columns in the BackTest.table. I would strive to first clean this mess up.

Also note that the vector with the replicates needs to be calculated `t` times, but in fact could just replicate the columns of the Weight.table once up front, since this procedure is identical for each row.

**EDIT**: ok, so now with the data I could take a closer look at what this evil code does. Basically, the columns are grouped, and for each group you have one weight by which you should divide the values from the columns in that group. So the author of the code, to save space, used a kind of run length encoding (0.0642 repeated 5 times, 0.7858 repeated 2 times etc.).

However, the rows of `Weight.table` have different numbers of repeats. This is a mess, and I would really, really encourage you to think what and how is being done to end up with optimally one data frame for use in your calculations.

Comment: I think this is an important information that I did not mention: Each row in BackTest.table actually has different numbers of stock types, bond types and cash types. E.g. There could be 5 stock types, 2 bond types, and 1 cash type in row 30, but 7 stock types, 1 bond type and 1 cash type in row 31. Like I said, it was just an example for the headers in BackTest, since each row contains different numbers of the fund combination. Anyways, thank you a lot for your time and insights. That really helps!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. Actually, I think that a wide format is not well suitable for this kind of data and I would either have a list data frame (where an element can be a list of arbitrary length), or long format. Your problems are because your data structures are so irregular.